# How to use isset function in php properly?

Tags: php, variables, isset

What is the difference and which is better?

This one:

```
 if(isset($_POST['name'])){

 }
```

or this one:

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 if(isset($name)){

 }
```

I wanna know if there are differences between the two codes, and which is more efficient to use. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the first one is correct, the latter will cause an error if it is not defined in the POST array

Comment: Thank you @RamRaider. Now I know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi The first one is right

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

 }
```

This will check `$_POST['name']` is set or not.

but

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
 if(isset($name)){

 }
```

this will check `$name` is set or not. and it will go inside if because whether `$_POST['name']` has value or not you have declared `$name`. So this will give wrong result

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jjjjjjjjjj if an answer solves your problem, don't forget to upvote and select it.

Comment: Note: `isset` checks if the variable has been defined and is not equal to `NULL`. Since doing the latter will define the variable as `NULL`, if the POST variable doesn't exist, `isset` will still return `false`.

Answer (score 6):

better still:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : 'empty';
```

Answer (score 0):

These two codes will do the same. They will both check if a variable is set.

In both cases you will check if `$_POST['name']` is set. If you're looking for efficiency, you should use the first one because creating new variables and handling data to them will always use more resources.

Comment: no they wont, the latter will return an error if the variable is undefined.

Comment: Of course, but that's not the point of his question. He wants to know what the difference is between these two conditions and which one is more efficient. And actually, yes, they will do the same : check if $_POST['name'] is set.

Comment: you obviously have a different definition of "same" than the rest of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

```
isset() Function:
The isset() function checks whether a variable is set, which means that it has tobe declared and is not NULL.
This function returns true if the variable exists and is not NULL, otherwise it returns false
Example:

<html>
<body>
<?php
$a = 0;
if (isset($a))
 {  echo "Variable 'a' is set.<br>";}
$b = null;
if (isset($b)) 
{  echo "Variable 'b' is set.";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```